# addMouseListener() won't work with JPanel under JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing

I add my customized panel onto JScrollPane. I also have another set of "tool" that will attach itself to my custom panel. The problem is, in these tool, it invokes `attached.addMouseListener(this)`. Normally, everything would function well, but when I have it inside JScrollPane, it won't function at all. My deduction is JScrollPane never gives window focus to its child component. Is there a way to get this around without having to change my attachment procedure? I want my 'tool' to specifically attach to my custom panel, not the scrollpane.

Comment: please show an sscce which demonstrates the problem

Comment: can you please to translate your question to the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), otherwise too hard to reproduce

Comment: It works well for me when I've added MouseListeners to components held by JScrollPane, so something different is in your code preventing it from working. That's why I too advise you create an [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) so we can identify the problem (though likely your creating the demo code will lead you to the problem in its solution).

Comment: Wait, let me shorten the code for sec

Comment: (checks watch) Time is relative.  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I hope I have understood the problem.
What about adding a MouseListener to the JScrollPane and then dispatch the event to the JPanel?
Somenthing like this:

```
    //JScrollPane Listener
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    jpanel.dispatchEvent(me);
    }
```

It's a little bit tricky, but so you don't have to change the JPanel Listener.